# nginx configuration for this .htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(127.0.0.1|XXX.254.185.XXX)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^66.6.(32|33|36|44|45|46). [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?(www.mydomain.org|pinterest.com|tumblr.com|facebook.com|plus.google.com|twitter.com) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot|Googlebot-Image|) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) byrev-wp-picshield.php?key=ABCD&src=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have change this rule for ngnix through this website http://winginx.com/htaccess   but it's not working..

Comment: What exactly is not working, and what is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I tried that converter, it ignored the conditions done on the remote address, and referrer, and user agent.

Comment: thanks friends i found this converter very useful http://www.anilcetin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem, and convert .htaccess rule with anilcetin.com.
And now, it's working.

THis is the sample

```
#HOTLINK PROTECTION START
if ($uri ~* ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$"){
set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($remote_addr !~* "^(127.0.0.1|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)$"){ #xxx.xxx.xxx.xx is your server ip
set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($remote_addr !~* "^66.6.(32|33|36|44|45|46|40)."){
set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
}
if ($http_referer !~* "^http(s)?://(www.)?(www.findhomeideas.info|translate.google.com|translate.googleusercontent.com|www.microsofttranslator.com|pinterest.com|tumblr.com|facebook.com|plus.google|twitter.com|googleapis.com|googleusercontent.com|ytimg.com|gstatic.com)"){
set $rule_0 4$rule_0;
}
if ($http_user_agent !~* "(googlebot|msnbot|baiduspider|slurp|webcrawler|teoma|photon|facebookexternalhit|facebookplatform|pinterest|feedfetcher|ggpht)"){
set $rule_0 5$rule_0;
}
if ($http_user_agent !~* "(photon|smush.it|akamai|cloudfront|netdna|bitgravity|maxcdn|edgecast|limelight|tineye)"){
set $rule_0 6$rule_0;
}
if ($http_user_agent !~* "(developers|gstatic|googleapis|googleusercontent|google|ytimg)"){
set $rule_0 7$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "7654321"){
rewrite /(.*) /byrev-wp-picshield.php?key=xxxx-xxxx&src=$1 last; #xxx-xxx is your key
}
#HOTLINK PROTECTION START
```